# ImageFolder cannot load classify dataset in Remote Linux Server

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, image-classification

"I am encountering an issue while using the classic image classification neural network ResNet-101 for an image classification task. Specifically, during the data loading phase, the program appears to be running but is stuck and not progressing. The interface looks as follows:

[image]

"I attempted to enter debugging mode and set breakpoints in the code segment responsible for loading the dataset. The feedback is as follows:

[image]

Here is a portion of the code：

```
def main():
    device = torch.device("cuda:2" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    print("using {} device.".format(device))

    data_transform = {
        "train": transforms.Compose([transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
                                     transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
                                     transforms.ToTensor(),
                                     transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])]),
        "val": transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(256),
                                   transforms.CenterCrop(224),
                                   transforms.ToTensor(),
                                   transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])}

    image_path = r"/home/sc/ClassicalNeuralNetwork/dataset/CGIARWheatGrowthStageChallenge"  # flower data set path
    assert os.path.exists(image_path), "{} path does not exist.".format(image_path)
    trains_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(root=os.path.join(image_path, "train"),
                                         transform=data_transform["train"],
                                          target_transform=None)
    # print(train_dataset)
    train_num = len(trains_dataset)

    # {'daisy':0, 'dandelion':1, 'roses':2, 'sunflower':3, 'tulips':4}
    flower_list = trains_dataset.class_to_idx
    cla_dict = dict((val, key) for key, val in flower_list.items())
    # write dict into json file
    json_str = json.dumps(cla_dict, indent=4)
    with open('class_indices.json', 'w') as json_file:
        json_file.write(json_str)

    batch_size = 4
    nw = min([os.cpu_count(), batch_size if batch_size > 1 else 0, 4])  # number of workers
    print('Using {} dataloader workers every process'.format(nw))

    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trains_dataset,
                                               batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True,
                                               num_workers=nw)

    validate_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(root=os.path.join(image_path, "val"),
                                            transform=data_transform["val"])
    val_num = len(validate_dataset)
    validate_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(validate_dataset,
                                                  batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False,
                                                  num_workers=nw)

    print("using {} images for training, {} images for validation.".format(train_num,
                                                                           val_num))

    net = resnet101(num_classes=7)
    net = net.cuda(device)`
```

And I also tried a convnet network, encountering the same error. Regardless of how I modify the name of the 'train_dataset', the same error persists during debugging.

but when I run it in my windows laptop,it works

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there's nothing wrong about your data loading code. Since your program is stuck, I guess the part most likely to cause problem is the way you set the device. Specifically, you have set the device as `cuda:2`, which may make the program to stuck when the `cuda:2` device is not available in your environment.

I suggest that you follow these steps to check whether the problem is caused by inappropriate GPU index:

1. Replace the `cuda:2` which `cuda` in your code.
2. Check `nvidia-smi` to determine which GPU is available.
3. Run your program with prefix `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2` to control the visible cuda devices. (Here I take `2` for example, and you may need to figure out the actual value by yourself.)

Although I'm not sure whether this is what caused your problem, it's a good idea to decouple your code from physical devices anyway.

Comment: codu is ok,and i found that Whenever I run any program that involves data reading, and the program fails to run, when I try to debug it, I always encounter the error as shown in Figure 2. When running the ResNet model, ConvXNet model, or even the script to convert CSV to XML, I always encounter this error